# Setting different thread number in construct heuristics and local search

Tags: multithreading, optaplanner

My Optaplanner version is 7.24.0

Can I set the thread number like bellows?

- Construct Heuristics : single thread
- Local Search: multi thread (for example 4)

Because, some data shows different result in construct heuristics.
I found that the data is affected by thread number.
(It shows always the same result every time in single thread.)

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use different move thread count in CH and LS. If you need that, you will have to run the solver twice - first just the CH, then just the LS.

That said, some comments:

- What you're describing sounds like a bug. Either a bug in OptaPlanner, or a bug in your domain. Construction Heuristics is a deterministic algorithm.
- Are you really using OptaPlanner **7**.24? That release is, by now, nearly 4 years old. You are missing out on so many performance improvements and bugfixes, and I don't even remember anymore if the behavior you are describing was something we've seen or fixed since. I strongly recommend you [upgrade to the latest version](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/upgradeRecipe8.html#_from_7_48_to_8_0_0_final); you'll be surprised by how easy it is, and by how much you gain.